# getting excel data and insert to mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, database, excel, xlsx

$data is getting the data from excel sheet and in the echo it displays it but it inserts null to mysql table..
here is my code after update.i dont understand why ???

```
$sql="insert into table_d values(";
        $data= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($i,$row)->getValue());
echo $data; // it works and display data
if($i !== $highestColumnNum){//big if 
    if($data != ''){
    $sql.=$data;
    $sql.=',';
    }
    else{   
    $sql.=$data;
    $sql.=',';
    }
    }//end big if

else{ //big else
         if($data!='')
         $sql.=$data;
         else
         $sql.='';

        }//end big else

    }$sql.=')';
       mysqli_query($connect,$sql)or die("FUQUERY: '$sql'");
```

Comment: thnx ,counted there are one opening and one closing parenthesis in the start of sql code and in the end of sql, sorry it is my first time to ask thats why first i set the image but then i knew that i can code , highestColumnNum is the number of columns in the excel file , and highestRow  is number of rows , i want to iterate by these 2 for loop and get value of each cell and then copy it to the mysql database .

Comment: In your code, it is true that there is 1 opening and 1 closing parenthesis. But the opening one is before the `for` loops, and the closing one is inside the loops. For me, it means that there will be only 1 opening, and a lot of closing parenthesis . First, imagine what should be the SQL query without code. Then compare with what the code is generating.

Comment: and also, much worse, is the mistake found in the answer below.

Comment: i appreciate your caring , but if you see the opening one is in the initializing of variable and wont change however i tried to put that in the for loop but was the same , then may you say right but these for loops is to repeating writing variable with different values of different cells , thats my idea and i cant find my mistake in this as i imagine it is right in syntax

Comment: the syntax for `INSERT` with `VALUES` is that each entry should be inside a pair of parenthesis. Anyway, if you look at user176717's answer, you will see another problem much more important to fix in your code, IMHO.

Comment: really i didnt understand from his answer , it is the same code i wrote in my program ,

Comment: Yes, this is your code, the answer shows you the cause of the problem. Your question was "tell me my error" : He told you.

Comment: bro i fixed my error but it is inserts null to the table , if u have time look at my question again updated it i will be thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides horizontal spacing, something might be missing from somewhere around here:

```
if($i !==$highestColumnNum)
    $sql.=$data.',';
    else
    $sql.=$data.'';
    mysqli_query($connect,$sql)or die (mysqli_error($connect));
```

And then you have this:

```
    $sql.=')';
    mysqli_query($connect,$sql)or die (mysqli_error($connect));
```

Comment: thnx but i dont understand whats my mistake , you wrote my code again

Comment: First, you are missing your brackets: `{` and `}` They may or may not be needed in this specific case, but **always use brackets for clarity**.
Especially since you have more closing brackets at the end of the script than you need.

Then, you run a query `or die`, then change the query, and run it again. If one doesn't work, the other won't run.

Comment: thnx to your advice i use brackets , but that closing brackets are nedded for ending dor loops when i have one loop for excel function and 2 loop to get value of excel cell by cell by columns and rows .and what i have to do with sql query ? i wanted to show me the sql error

Comment: You can't fix your SQL error until you fix your logic errors. Only then will you see that you are calling a mysqli_query, not getting a result and `die`ing, then trying the query again, which will never happen. If you're only interested in fixing the SQL, then change `or die (mysqli_error($connect))` to `or die("FUQUERY: '$sql'");` so you know what you have actually created.

Comment: thnx alot for your advice and solution it helped me find my error and fixed it now it wont give error but it inserts null to the table if u have time look at my question again after update i will be thankful alot

Comment: Your sql statement appears to look like `$sql="insert into table_d values(4,)` which would add null to the second column.